# pass to the query array one element at a time (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a small piece of javascript code snippet that passes an array to the request

```
let input = range.find('input');
let values = [];


if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
  values.push($(this).data('value'));
}

input.val(values);
```

When an element is clicked, the class `active` is assigned to it and the value of this element is sent to the request.

Now the code works so that when you select several elements, something like this will go into the query `[values]: 1,2,3`

The question is, is it possible on the Javascript side to make the array go into the request a little differently. That is, in the request itself it looked like this:

```
[values]
[values][]: 1
[values][]: 2
[values][]: 3
```

html

```
<div class="range">
<input type="hidden" id="values" class="form-control" name="[values]" value="1,2,3">                    
  <span class="it active" data-value="1">value 1</span>
  <span class="it active" data-value="2">value 2</span>
  <span class="it active" data-value="3">value 3</span>
  <span class="it" data-value="4">value 4</span>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

I need to make it so that if we find the `active` class, then we get its `data-value` and form a new input with this value, which will have `name="[values][]"` and `value="1"`

Let's say there are two `active` classes that have `data-value="1"` and `data-value="3"`.
From this in JS we form two inputs in order to get this in the code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="values---0" class="form-control" name="[values][]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" id="values---2" class="form-control" name="[values][]" value="3">
```

=======================================

```js
$(function() {
$(".range .it").click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass('active');
$("<input>", {
      value: $(this).data("value"),
      name: "[value][]",
      type: "hidden",
      id: "value--" + $(this).data("value")
    }).appendTo(".range");
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="range">
  <input type="hidden" id="values" class="form-control" name="[values]" value="">
  <span class="it" data-value="1">value 1</span>
  <span class="it" data-value="2">value 2</span>
  <span class="it" data-value="3">value 3</span>
  <span class="it" data-value="4">value 4</span>
</div>
```

Now when I click on any of the values, active is assigned to this class, when you click again, this class is deleted. But at the same time, inputs are added with each click, and can go to infinity. I need that when there is an active class, the input is added, when the active class is removed, the input should be deleted along with it

Comment: Show your related HTML to allow us to formulate better answers.  In this limited context you meaning of "request" is a little vague here.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss added a piece of html that I get as output

Comment: can you please explain what you exactly mean by "go into request differently".
For example you may say "every odd indexed value must have odd: prefix before the value". this is a silly example but i hope you get my point. I read the question multiple times and im still not sure what exactly you want

Comment: @nikoss now an array of the form [values]: 1,2,3 goes to the input with js, I showed a piece of code that forms it

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your expected result would look like program-side? Do you want us to break the array into multiple little arrays?

Comment: @nikoss and I need an array to go into the request in the form [values]
[values][]: 1
[values][]: 2
[values][]: 3 I don't know how else to explain

Comment: request I mean payload in the network

Comment: What "request"?  Are you referring to a form submission?  Why do you need to change the format of what's being submitted?  (Technically an `<input>` is just a string, so you can construct that value *any* way you want when setting it to the `<input>`.)

Comment: im sorry i still dont quite get what you really want you mix and match terms such as going into inputs and requests. What request are you talkin about that i have no clue .
All i can see in your code is that you are finding an input then getting some values of elementes with class "Active" and pushing it into an array. then setting  inputs value with that array. I am sorry i cant help you with this much info however my advice is first isolate the problem and create an MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: you dont have a problem with neither request or getting elements so please dont mention those to simplify things just say i have an array of data in this form and i want it to be in this form and i dont know how to do.

If you just want to modify the contents of an array and create a new array from it please check Array.prototype.map method

Comment: Sorry everyone, I updated the post at the end, now everything should become clear

Comment: @brokenheart the update makes less sense, sorry. There are many things that do not make sense, to start with, why `name="[values]"` or `name="[values][]"` Are you updating a form or performing an AJAX call. What is your handler expecting? Why not just send an array of values? Should it be JSON data being sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function makeInput(val) {
    return $("<input>", {
      value: val,
      name: "[value][]",
      type: "hidden",
      id: "value---" + val
    });
  }

  function reloadRange(sel) {
    $(".hidden").empty();
    $(sel).each(function(i, el) {
      $(".hidden").append(makeInput($(el).data("value")));
    });
  }

  $(".range .it").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    reloadRange(".active");
  });
});
```

```css
.range span.it {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
}

.range span.active {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="range">
  <input type="hidden" id="values" class="form-control" name="[values]" value="1,2,3">
  <span class="it active" data-value="1">value 1</span>
  <span class="it active" data-value="2">value 2</span>
  <span class="it active" data-value="3">value 3</span>
  <span class="it" data-value="4">value 4</span>
  <div class="hidden"></div>
</div>
```

When you click on an `active` class, it created the HTML.

```
<div class="hidden">
  <input value="1" name="[value][]" type="hidden" id="value---1">
  <input value="3" name="[value][]" type="hidden" id="value---3">
</div>
```

**Updated**

When User clicks on an item, the class is toggled and the `input` items are rebuilt.

Comment: Yes, this is what I need, only there is one moment. Initially, all classes are inactive, and only when we click somewhere, the class becomes active and an input is added, I understand how to do this

Comment: But even when we click again on the active class, it should become inactive, and the input should be deleted too

Comment: I added my code fragment to the post, on clicks the active class is added and removed, but how to do the same with the input?

Comment: @brokenheart you did not include these details in your original post. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Added an example and one more small description to the post